# How to create a secure "call home" suport capability for an instrument?

Tags: linux, security, connection

I'm an embedded engineer (not a network guru) building a piece of Linux-based equipment (a portable measurement instrument) that is normally not connected to the Internet, but we need to make it possible for the equipment to "call home" for support, including updates and troubleshooting, in a manner that compromises neither the product's security, nor the customer's network security nor our own company network.

The "call home" capability will be completely controlled by the user, perhaps by pressing a physical button to activate it, after the equipment has been connected to whatever network the customer chooses to use.  For prototype and demonstrations systems, this network could be at someone's home or office or even via a phone connection (the equipment will contain only a wired Ethernet port, and the customer would need to provide a wired AP if WiFi access is desired).

Making the connection should require no per-call configuration at the user's end, nor within our box, so I'm thinking we can require the customer to provide DHCP, and not much else.  We can also require the customer to first contact us before pressing the "call home" button, so we can have our support interface up only when needed.

When a unit does "call home", it merely makes a connection to a company system, doing nothing else until an engineer (well, me) directly connects to it.  Other than the existence of the connection, we should get no (or minimal) information about the network the customer is using.  So I'm thinking some kind of SSH connection, but that's as far as I have gotten.

If possible, it should "feel" as if I'm connecting locally, as if the unit were on my desk (perhaps with much more latency, loss, and minimal bandwidth).

But I have no idea whatsoever how to make an SSH connection (if that's the right tool to use for this) as two separate halves: The remote unit "calls" somewhere, presumably on one of our company systems, then that system notifies an engineer (me) that a "call home" has been initiated, then waits for the engineer to connect, forming the other half of the connection.

The connection need not identify the remote system (make, model, serial number, version, etc.): I'd do that manually after logging in securely.

If needed, I can create a new system on our end (Linux, BSD, Windows, whatever, physical or VM) that can be dedicated to just this function.  I can get at least one static port mapped out to our corporate WAN, if needed (but something I'd prefer to avoid, if possible).

Ideally, I'd also like for there to be minimal information in the equipment itself, so that possession of the equipment by an adversary (or competitor) could not compromise customer or company networks, other units, nor the call-home technique itself.  From what little I know, I'd guess a hostname or IP address, a port number, and a key would be needed, but less would be better!

I'd also like the system to require manual intervention at both ends, with minimal automation that can be buggy or be compromised.  Once we implement and test the initial system, automation could be added as our experience with it, and confidence in it, grows.

That's about as far as my thinking has taken me.  Beyond this, I'm pretty much clueless.  Am I on the right track?  What pieces am I missing?  Is this already a popular thing to do, and I simply don't know what it is called?  How simple and stupid can this capability be made for a couple of prototype systems?

EDIT: If it wasn't obvious already, please assume I'm a networking idiot who can be trusted only to follow an explicit recipe, and not much more.  KISS applies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: as long as no "real" answer is there I just provide my more or less theoretical thoughts with hope it helps.

Without reading in detail, I found http://www.vdomck.org/2005/11/reversing-ssh-connection.html to reverse a ssh-connection. If that is easy to follow (it should be easy, just ssh -R basically, see also http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/ssh_tunnelling.html) it means your remote device could connect to your network (and "Pete" is your Partner at the customer). The problem is that initiating a ssh-connection without user/password requires a authentication- private key on that device (so in non-friendly hands).

You could place a dumb ssh-server with no private data and no special access and even the password you could set just for that single connection (and tell your partner "Pete" via phone), let your phantasie play a bit to get a static half "ImGenious$%" and a dynamic half "1243" so you can give a short easy dynamic half over phone.

Then from that dumb ssh-server you can connect to your device as in the article.

Comment: Looks like the unit would reverse-SSH to a port on a company machine, then I'd SSH to that same port to make the connection on my end.  No other kind of proxy needed?

Comment: I would suggest using port 80 (http) or 443 (https-port) for that reason, because IT- departements are used to let it open. ;-) You just ssh to localhost at that port to enter the already established connection. And creating a key pair for every device is a bit boring, but really a good solution. You enable that ssh-key just after the phone call, you can even automate that on the machine with very simple perl or bash- scripting like "phone_accept m3311" to activate the ssh-key for m3311.

Comment: Anything like "Key Generation and Management for Dummies?"  Ideally I'd like there to be per-unit keys and per-developer keys so that any developer can connect with any unit, but not have to create all the possible combinations of key for all developers and all units.  Is this possible?

Comment: ssh-keygen is not too hard, http://blog.burlock.org/open-source/90-introduction-to-ssh-public-keys. You could wrap it into a bash-script like "phone_generate m3311" to generate the file "id_m3311" instead of "id_rsa". The only irritating thing here is: normally you keep the private key private (and secret) and the public key public, here you put the "private" key into your device. Activation of such a key in your controller is then mainly file copying.

Comment: We have a DMZ that contains a NetBSD box that would be perfect for the machine-in-the-middle application!  It should greatly simplify key management.  I'll look into it Tuesday.

Comment: Comment me again if bash/perl is not your friend. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the call home functionality uses SSH to connect to your office.  This requires your customer's network provides DHCP, Internet access and DNS capability.  It also requires them to allow outbound connections on port 22.  The latter is possibly an issue for some security minded customers who want to prevent unknown egress of data.

You will need a certificate for your SSH server so the certificate is valid for the domain name you choose.  You will also need to make sure the SSH client on the server is configured to accept the signature of your server.

It sounds like the number of devices you will be maintaining is relatively low.  For this reason, I would suggest generating unique public/private key pairs for each device.  You can then load the public key into your server so logins are accepted via keys only.

If a device is compromised or stolen, you can delete the appropriate key from your server.  The device will not be able to login again.  The private key on the device only has value because you have decided to accept the associated public key on login.  Remove this and it has no value.  The added benefit is that you can identify a device by the key it has used to login (e.g. you can associate each key with a different user).  You can then tie up the login with the information about the device/customer that you store on your systems.

If you use [reverse SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work) you can have the device connect in.  Once you're ready, you can use the reverse part to connect through the tunnel that the device and your server have already setup to perform the maintenance.

Comment: Yes, I was looking into creating per-unit keys based on salt with the serial number, but hadn't gotten too far with it.  Thanks for the pointer to Reverse SSH!